# scrapy exponential backoff to restart spider crawl after every exception

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'd like to have a scrapy spider that runs until completion, but can start and stop in the middle as exceptions are reached.

Each time an error happens, which could be something like:

```
def parse_inner_page(self, response):
    if "Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot" in response.body:
        # want to stop the spider here and have the entire spider
        # remember states of request and retry after 2 seconds, 
        # and if that fails, wait 2^2 seconds, 2^3 after that, etc...
        pass
```

so this requires:

1. Storage and update of some external state `n` (for 2^`n` seconds to wait)
2. Ability to stop the spider gracefully from within the script (see above)
3. Ability to restart the spider, including all responses/requests that failed and have them start back at the same spot in the crawl (depth, metadata, and all).

Is this possible in scrapy, and what would be the best way to go about coding this?

I think the answer is to use scrapy `jobs`, and I've started to put together a Python script like so:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from myproject.spiders.mymodule import MySpider

#https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html

process = CrawlerProcess({'JOBDIR': './job'})
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

But should I have a while loop around this? How do I send a signal from inside the crawl `process` back to the outside where I can restart, etc?

How can I close the spider from within one of the spider's functions - do I need to simulate hitting Ctrl+C?

```
import subprocess
import signal

process = subprocess.Popen(..)
process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: Have you considered the [HTTP Cache middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache)? The code would run from the beginning each time, but the slow part (downloading responses) would be really fast. However, you might need to implement your own cache policy class to prevent the caching of failed requests.

Comment: As for closing the spider from a request handler, simply raise [CloseSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider).